# Want capture image remain in container of flutter app

Tags: android, image, flutter, tabbar

I have three tab. One of the tab is for edit photo page (retrieve image which already have in  API, edit and return capture image to API with Update button in that page). All is work and fine. But after capture image with camera, and change to other tab and return back to this tab (in this state not save), Already capture image not show and only API image show. I capture again to save. I want to remain the capture image in container although I don't save to API and change tab.

[This is picture of my app contain tab bar view which contain edit image tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atIyn.jpg)

This is my tab bar view dart file.

```
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final tabText = TextStyle(fontSize: width * 0.03);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'EDIT CLIENT',
          style: new TextStyle(color: accentColor, fontFamily: 'Dosis'),
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size(40, 40),
          child: Container(
            height: getScreenHeightRation(40.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFF0C185),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[600]),
              //0xFFF0C185
            ),
            child: TabBar(
              indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
              //isScrollable: true,
              //change here
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFD2A368),
              ),
              tabs: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
                  child: Tab(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage('assets/images/icon_ext/menu.png'),
                          size: 12,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Text('Customer Data',style: tabText, ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
                  child: Tab(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage('assets/images/icon_ext/image.png'),
                          size: 12,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Text('Profile',style: tabText, )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Tab(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage('assets/images/icon_ext/placeholder.png'),
                          size: 12,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Text('Location',style: tabText, )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
              controller: tabController,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: accentColor),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: [
          EditClientInformation(
            customerNo: widget.customerNo,
            branchId: _branchId,
            defaultBranchId: _defaultBranchId,
            userId: _userId,
            systemFormatDate: _systemFormatDate,
          ),
          EditClientProfile(
            customerNo: widget.customerNo,
            branchId: _branchId,
            defaultBranchId: _defaultBranchId,
            userId: _userId,
            systemFormatDate: _systemFormatDate,
          ),
          EditClientMap(
            customerNo: widget.customerNo,
            branchId: _branchId,
            defaultBranchId: _defaultBranchId,
            userId: _userId,
            systemFormatDate: _systemFormatDate,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is capture image tab.

```
  Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 300.0,
                        height: 170.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          border:
                              Border.all(width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Container(
                            width: 170.0,
                            height: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                              //border: Border.all(width: 1, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: _profileCaptImg == ""
                                    ? NetworkImage(_profileImg)
                                    : FileImage(profile),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        right: 62.0,
                        top: 0.0,
                        child: _profileCaptImg != ''
                            ? GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    profile = null;
                                    _profileCaptImg = '';
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 20.0,
                                  height: 20.0,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.close,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: profileImgPicker,
                        heroTag: null,
                        child: new Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: You could have a parent widget that stores the state and passes it to the children.

Comment: But when I change tab and return back to this scaffold state change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
/// Add with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin:
class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

/// Add these 2 lines:
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

/// Add super.build(context) to your build method
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    
    return YourWidgets();
  }

}
```

Comment: Does this AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin keep all widget state in a stateful class? I don't want all widget in a class to wantKeepAlive, because fetch data from API need to change when change tab, only capture image want to keep alive although change scaffold before return to API.

Comment: Add `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` only to the one you want to keep the state.